# How do i get current slot number onchain?

Tags: anchor, anchor-test

I'm trying to get the slot number at runtime. In evm we can just call `block.number` to get current block number, i need something equivalent to `block.number`.

I tried `SlotHistory::get()` but it throws an error in test environment when using `anchor test`. I also tried to give it as account in context but it threw another error saying sysvar address mismatch.

I guess something is wrong with test environment.

---

Edit

I found the error message `Unsupported sysvar`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Through the clock sysvar

```
use solana_sdk::clock::Clock;

let slot = Clock::get()?.slot;
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `Clock` instead of `SlotHistory`